# Round corners for external element

Tags: html, css, border

I have external div with round corner. It's children doesn't have round corner but I want the external div's round corners cover the children's corners.

I used first-child and last child selector to do it and it works good only for new devices (new versions of browsers).

Here's my code:

```
CSS:
.external
{
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #68ACDD;
    margin: 0 0 1px 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.external:first-child
{
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}
.external:last-child
{
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}
table.address-table
{
    background: white;
    border-color: #68acdd;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

HTML:
<div class="external">
    <table class="address-table">
        <tr class="">
            <td>some text</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table class="address-table">
        <tr class="">
            <td>some other text</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table class="address-table">
        <tr class="">
            <td>some other text</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

And in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x82Lyy6j/)

My problems is with the old devices (with old browsers): the corners doesn't exist (it's just a white).
How can I solve it the old way? The internal element builds on runtime so I can have some logic and insert the borders wherever needed, but I'm looking for more elegant way (use only html and css).

Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't think this is possible with other way using html and css only. Or you need give statically first and last div round corner.

Comment: @ketan Thank you. I'll do it the old way ...